# how to name classes in CSS of table

Tags: html, css

what does this mean

```
table.my tr{
border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

mean in CSS classes. How to manipulate them? Can we give simple name like

```
my{
border-top{
border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

in tr tag of html table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `table.my tr` css selector means "all `tr` tag inside a `table` tag with a classe `my` ".
You can see all selector here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

If you want to only use the `my` selector, you will need to give the `my` class to each tr tag in your html file.